# how do u want to open this file in cmd C++

Tags: c++

I am still very new to c++ , And i cant seem to compile my very first c++ hello world program after writing my program i go to command prompt and change the directory to desktop because that is where i have saved my program then enter hello.cpp (hello.cpp is the name of my program)and instead of compiling it, It shows me a message saying how do u want to open this file? even thought i already installed mingw ,and changed the environment variables

[image]

Comment: You have it opened, now you need to compile it (not open it). Look at mingw documentation or the tutorial where you got this hello world.

Comment: Did you try invoking the mingw C++ compiler? Since `hello.cpp` in a command line tries to open `hello.cpp`, not compile it.

Comment: try `dir C:\Users\Programming\Desktop`, then `gcc hello.cpp` and then `./a`

Comment: This link might help hopefully: https://rupinderjeetkaur.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/run-a-cc-program-on-terminal-using-gcc-compiler/

Answer (score 3):

compile your code to create `.exe` by below command.

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe
```

[MinGW for First Time Users HOWTO](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW_for_First_Time_Users_HOWTO)